# How to make a square root fit to data in Julia 1.0

Tags: package, julia, glm, least-squares, square-root

I have a very simple question. How would one fit a square root model to a dataset in Julia. I'm currently using the `GLM` package, which works very well with linear data. I need to plot a phase velocity as a function of string tension, and it seems like `@formula(v ~ sqrt(T))` does not work in

```
import GLM, DataFrames # No global namespace imports
df = DataFrames.DataFrame(
  v = [1, 1.5, 1.75],
  T = [1, 2, 3]
)
fit = GLM.glm(GLM.@formula(v ~ T^(1/2)), vs)
```

Is `GLM` at all viable here, or do I need to resort to another package such as `LsqFit`?

Comment: You could always calculate the sqrt of the data before putting it in the dataframe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sqrt` in your model formula. Just do it e.g. like this:

```
GLM.lm(GLM.@formula(v ~ sqrt(T)), df)
```

if you want to fit a linear model use `lm` function and a second argument should be a data frame, which is `df` in your case.